# Where is the certificate for Open Id Connected App in Salesforce?

Tags: integration, oauth2, open-id-connect

I have created a connected app and used scope -"Allow access to your unique identifier (openid)". I am expecting a "id token" which would be a JWT token. But where from would I get the digital certificate so that client can verify  the digital signature of JWT token?

Answer (score 1):

Use the published public keys to verify the signature in the response is a valid Salesforce signature.

http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_forcecom_security_public_key.htm

Public keys here: https://login.salesforce.com/id/keys

Comment: Hi Krigi, I don't think that the above option is any way related to OpenIdConnect. As far as my understanding is concerned, the above option is  to validate  incoming JWT token as mentioned in url-"https://dreamevent.secure.force.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=0". "Id_token" is something that is send by Salesforce when the scope contains 'openid'. And since this itself is kind of JWT , I am confused how the client would be able to verify the same since no digital certificate is generated when such scope is selected.

Comment: https://dreamevent.secure.force.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=0

Comment: Deep, right. Revised answer above.

Comment: Cool thnks krigi